# Why nginx response time much larger than their upstream?

Tags: nginx, https

I am running nginx as loadbalancer to serve HTTPS request with ~1000 average req/s. All request is proxying to other 8 nginx.

From log, average response time for nginx-loadbalancer is ~300ms. But, looking more at the logs, I see quite few request (0.5%) has request time of nginx-loadbalancer much larger than upstream response time. Here, my log

```
    Time        remote_address            request_time      status      upstream_response_time      upstream_addr   body_bytes_sent     request  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
July 4th 2015, 12:57:40.000 36.79.115.36        48.659  200 14.185  172.16.1.34:6081    46,890  GET /sys...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 114.79.32.74        5.44    200 5.440   172.16.1.16:8080    53,525  GET /v2/...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 36.68.179.9         7.841   200 1.255   172.16.1.19:8080    158 POST /pro...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 114.125.172.41      7.19    200 3.643   172.16.1.34:6081    46,355  GET /sys...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 114.125.169.243     11.189  200 0.065   172.16.1.53:8080    11,416  GET / HT...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 202.72.215.103      5.996   200 1.010   172.16.1.17:8080    20,969  GET /nor...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 114.125.175.62      5.018   200 5.018   172.16.1.53:8080    23,276  GET /v2/...
July 4th 2015, 12:57:39.000 114.124.1.75        6.979   200 1.219   172.16.1.21:8080    157 POST /pro...
```

Below is average nginx stats for 10 minutes capture

```
desc                        avg 
--------------------------+-------
active_connections (m)      22.4 K
reading (m)                 7   
waiting (m)                 18.9 K
writing (m)                 895
```

I dont know how to trace the cause that make response_time load balancer and upstream differ greatly. Is anyone has idea?

Rgds,

Comment: Couldn't it be just slow clients (with bad network speed)?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_request_time "request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution; time elapsed *between the **first bytes were read** from the client and the log write after the **last bytes were sent** to the client*"

Comment: Thank for your fast reply. Maybe you are right. I'm glad to know that it is nothing to do with nginx config.